# boot problem on asus x550v

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, asus

I have a new Asus x550v free dos, downloaded ubuntu 16.04 from the official website, make a live boot flash disk then enter bios setting disable secure boot and boot on the flash disk but the installation didn't even begin and it freezes.

The first time I tried without disabling secure boot, it showed a message "Force UEFI installation?" I chose "continue in UEFI mode", the installation continued normally but at the final phase "Reboot" it froze there, force shut down then start the system without the boot support, the system works fine, installed unity tweak tool, adblock on firefox... then shut down..but when I try to start it again it freezs and show:

```
[      1.272768] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 10ecc0 ffffffff (1v40822c)
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean,185521/60530688 files, 4744830/242111488 blocks
[       7.394772] tpm crp MSFT 0101:00 can't request region for ressource mem 0xfed40080 0xfed40fff
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

The solution was to change graphics card driver. Todo so, I entered recovery mode, and typed in the following:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting the graphical login screen arrived.

I've found the description here: 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325271

The current driver version found on http://www.geforce.com/drivers is 375, so I changed that bit.